# Why isn't the car straight when following a curve?

Tags: animation, bezier-curves, constraints

I have made this small animation with drivers with the help of this great community.

Unfortunately my cars are following the curves in one direction in a wierd way like this:

[image]

on a straight line i would have expected that the green car is exactly on the line...but it isn't. Can anybody tell me, why this happens? or how to make it right?

my settings:

[image][image]

blend file:

[image]

Comment: hello please share your file: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: done.............

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you zoom on your curve, we can see that these 2 vertices are not aligned, it must mess the normals:

[image]

[image]

Align them on the Y axis and it will work fine. Also maybe add some vertices on this part to make sure the car will stay straight all along:

[image]

Comment: thanks again and again! You are my hero! ;)